# When are compiled assets being cached in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

When I precompile my assets for a rails 3.1 app with `rake assets:precompile` it spits out an old cached version if nothing changes in the asset files. I can tell because my erb is making use of a constant that I was trying to change elsewhere in my app. One work around is to alter one of the css files (eg by adding a space etc) before re-precompiling but this is a pain and I would like to try and disable this caching if it is possible. Any ideas???

Comment: You could add a `rake assets:clean` to be sure, but that is only a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @mliebelt, I will give it a try. It is certainly better than adding a new line to my application.css.scss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the pipeline - the ERB is evaluated only once when you precompile. The value at compile time is the value you get in the file.

The caching is based on the checking the timestamp of the files. You could run Sprockets in production without precompiling (this is called live compiling), but you cannot turn off the caching because the performance would be dreadful - every single request would require Sprockets to recompile all the files.

Sorry :-(